# OpenCV: cvWarpAffine unhandled exception

Tags: opencv

The code is:

```
CvMat *rotMapMat = cvCreateMat(2, 3, CV_32SC1);
cv2DRotationMatrix(center, angle, 1, rotMapMat);
cvWarpAffine(image, dst, rotMapMat);
```

First problem: The cv2DRotationMatrix is not correctly computing the matrix. 
Then I've changed that function by my version cv2DRotationMatrixOwn
But there is another problem, the second: The cvWarpAffine always fails with unhandled exception error.

And I can't use debugger and call stack doesn't show the needed functions called before the place when an error occured.
Why does it happen? 
Size of st image is made big enough.

EDIT1: Opencv version 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rotMapMat` has to be floating-point matrix. `CV_32S` type is not supported by `cv2DRotationMatrix` and `cvWarpAffine`. Change it to CV_32F to fix your problems.